# Can a web browser pop up a blank alert box on its own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, browser, flot

In my partner's program, when the `<select>` tag changes, it will redirect to that page again with the `option` value, and it will be refreshed, and draw several charts using `JQuery flot`.

However after it is redirected, before refreshed and drawing charts, sometimes, there is an alert box popping up.

My partner said that the program is fine and that it must be the web browser that popped up a blank box because of wrong interpretation or incomplete download of  code.

I think, the problem should be in JavaScript code, and I am not sure about that. Does anyone have the same experience? Can a web browser  pop up a blank alert box?

Thanks anyone who consider this.

Comment: Look for an alert. There has to be an alert, confirm or prompt

Comment: Install webdeveloper plugin in Firefox. Load the page, view "Information, Javascript" and search for alert

Comment: Is that mean that the problem should be caused by javascript not by web browser?

Comment: In chrome, I have to click `ok` to be next. In firefox, it poped up and then disappear quickly by itself without being clicked `ok` button.

Comment: Then it is NOT an alert. It must be a div or a window.open that closes itself. Do you have a site you can show us?

Comment: Now, when I using firebug, I got an information `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user`
`resource:///components/nsPrompter.js`
`Line 457` @mplungjan I have six `<iframe>` in the page, sometimes I need click `ok` several times in firefox and the screen become more and more clear during I clicked `ok` button. It is black at beginning.

Comment: So you do have a prompt. I just cannot believe it can disappear unless the reload makes it disappear. Ok, now search for prompt( in the code

Comment: thanks mplungjan, I didnt find any `prompt` code, problem still exists. Maybe it's the code `iframe`. and maybe not. anyway thanks again.